# Why compiler error when defining a variable if block without braces?

Tags: java, javac

Why does Java compiler suggest grammar error in the following code?

```
  1 public class Test {
  2   public static void main(String[] args) {
  3     if (true)
  4       int b = 0;
  5   }
  6 }

Test.java:4: '.class' expected
      int b = 0;
          ^
Test.java:4: not a statement
      int b = 0;
      ^
Test.java:4: illegal start of expression
      int b = 0;
            ^
Test.java:4: ';' expected
      int b = 0;
             ^
4 errors
```

Comment: Q: Where can you use `b`? A: Only on line 4, so it is pointless.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was just testing Java compiler ;)

Comment: In which case you can assume if the compiler doesn't allow it either a) it doesn't make sense or b) you are unlikely to change it so accept it.

Comment: Obligatory note on using [multiline braceless ifs being a bad idea](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java doesn't let you define a variable in an if statement without curly braces, since it could never be used (since there can be no other line it could be referenced from - it will be out of scope and therefore unavailable as soon as you hit the next line.)

If you put curly braces around the if statement, it will compile fine:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       if (true) {
           int b = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Technically, it could be used on the same line, but any variable which uses it could not be used ;)

Comment: Thanks for making me learn something new that java would have otherwise never told.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add curly braces while defining a variable inside **if**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (true) {
        int b = 0;
    }

}
```

Since when you write without curly braces

```
if()
//something
```

Only that line executes and in that place if you are trying to define a variable that doesn't make any sense.

And the compiler smart enough to complain :)